# Google font problems on wordpress child page

Tags: wordpress, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

I have some problems with GFonts. My website try to call http://fonts.googleapis.com/css but didn't find nothing. I think that's because are not specify some parameters. (es. http://www.initiative.it/test/contattaci/)

In Home Page (www.initiative.it/test) I haven't this problem and montserrat load correctly. Why? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you should provide some missing parameter like 
`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">`.

Note `family=Roboto` in the URL. In you page I cannot see any parameter provided as a result you have status code 400 Bad Request.

The same issue is happening on the Home page. Just open the browser console and you will see it.